# Interpolation of a 3D regular griddata using scipy.interpolate.Rbf

Tags: scipy, interpolation, hdf5, polynomials, cubic-spline

This h5 file contains the information of an analytical function on a regular 3D gird. For interpolation purpose, I have got very poor result using the Regulargridinterpolator here. Now, I want to test `scipy.interpolate.Rbf` interpolator for my data set. Can anyone help me to do that? I had a look at the documentation of this interpolator but didn't understand properly.

I have created a h5 file like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import gradient
import h5py
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

def f(x,y,z):
    return ( -1 / np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2))

#grid
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 32)  # since the boxsize is 320 Mpc/h
y = np.linspace(0, 100, 32)
z = np.linspace(0, 100, 32)


mesh_data = phi_an(*np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij', sparse=True))


#create h5 file
h5file = h5py.File('analytic.h5', 'w')
h5file.create_dataset('/x', data=x)
h5file.create_dataset('/y', data=y)
h5file.create_dataset('/z', data=z)
h5file.create_dataset('/mesh_data', data=mesh_data)

h5file.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean test your data? Does this have to be on data from a h5 file?